¿Por qué la tabla del jDialog no se llena de con los datos de la consulta?
Tengo un problema con una tabla de un jDialog, ya que al momento de abrirlo, la tabla me aparece vacía:

Sin embargo, ya hice depuración del proyecto con un punto de interrupción, y veo que la consulta a la base de datos y el método que llena la tabla sí se ejecutan de manera correcta.
Desde aquí llamo al JDialog:
String Linea = txt_Linea.getText();
    
    if(!Linea.isEmpty())
    {
        ObtenerAplicacion();
        
        frm_CatMateriales frmCAT = new frm_CatMateriales(null, true);
        frmCAT.setTitle("Catalogo materiales");
        frmCAT.SetDatos(patin, counter);
        frmCAT.setVisible(true);

        if("1".equals(frmCAT.getValue()))
        {
            ArrayList<materiales_DAO> data = frmCAT.lista;

            for(materiales_DAO m : data)
            {
                Object[] fila = 
                {
                    m.getClave_Material(),
                    m.getDescripcion()
                };

                modeloA.addRow(fila);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                      "Por favor seleccione una linea del producto.", 
                                      "TOP-SUELAS", 
                                      JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

Este es el método donde se obtiene la aplicación:
private void ObtenerAplicacion()
{
    switch(txt_Linea.getText())
    {
        case "BRU":
            patin = 32;
            break;
            
        case "JHON":
            counter = 12;
            break;
            
        case "NIO":
            patin = 13;
            break;
            
        case "JORDI":
            patin = 27;
            counter = 21;
            break;
    }
}

Y este es el método que se encarga de cargar los datos a la tabla:

Este recibe los datos del formulario padre:

    public void SetDatos(int pat, int count)
    {
        this.patin = pat;
        this.counter = count;
        
        CargarDatosTabla();
    }


Y aquí ya se reciben los datos y se cargan a la tabla:

    private void CargarDatosTabla()
    {
        material = new materiales_DAO();
        material.setPatin(patin);
        material.setCounter(counter);
        
        ArrayList<materiales_DAO> data = materiales.getByFamilia(material);
        
        if(!data.isEmpty())
        {
            for(materiales_DAO m : data)
            {
                Object[] fila = 
                {
                    m.getClave_Material(),
                    m.getDescripcion(),
                    m.getDescripcion_Corta(),
                    false
                };
                
                modeloM.addRow(fila);
            }
        }
    }

Aquí muestro la imagen donde se ve que la consulta sí obtiene resultados:


¿Cuándo seteás el modelo a la tabla?

No lo hago, solo pongo el código de esta forma: private void TableActions()     {         modeloM = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Materiales.getModel();         jt_Materiales.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);         sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modeloM);         jt_Materiales.setRowSorter(sorter);     }

¿E intentaste hacer el setModel luego de cargar los datos al modelo?

No, porque según el articulo que vi, solo se cargaba el modelo de esta forma, aunque no recuerdo la explicación, de hecho todas mis tablas las cargo de la misma manera sin nungún problema

Veo que imprimies que tienes información pero , en este loop, imprime los valores de getClave_Material() y getDescripcion(). para asegurar que se tengan los datos correctos:   for(materiales_DAO m : data) {
System.out.println("Clave Material: " + m.getClave_Material());
System.out.println("Descripción: " + m.getDescripcion());

En ese loop, la variable data, es un ArrayList<> que hago con los registros que se seleccionan de la tabla, la tabla si funcionaba, pero hoy que la abri para acabar unos detalles que me faltaban, ya no mostro los registros

El problema puede estar en estos puntos:

Modelo no vinculado: Verifica que el modelo (modeloM) esté correctamente asignado a la tabla.
Actualizar la tabla: Usa modeloM.fireTableDataChanged() para
refrescar la tabla después de añadir datos.
Consulta de datos: Asegúrate de que la lista obtenida de la base de
datos no esté vacía, por descartar...
Paso de parámetros: Confirma que los valores de patin y counter se
pasan bien al método.

Finalmente reinicio del modelo para asegurarte de no estar reemplazando o reiniciando el modelo accidentalmente.
Salu2

Hola, todo eso que mencionas lo hice y no me genero ningún resultado, al final tuve que borrar el formulario y hacer uno nuevo, y resulto, hasta el momento no he encontrado el motivo por el que pasa eso, Saludos

Si había algún ActionListener, TableModelListener o similar que pudiera estar interfiriendo con el  refresco de la tabla o del modelo, a veces esos errores no son obvios y lo mejor es lo que ha hecho ya que pueden detener la funcionalidad de la interfaz.

No, solo esta y estaba el código que compartí aquí, mi opinión es que a lo mejor moví algo sin darme cuenta que corrompió la conexión del modelo con el jTable. Según lo que tengo entendido, la forma en que uso el modelo es para poder filtrar datos, agregarlos o eliminarlos.
